# Convergent sequence of continuous real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ with infinitely discontinuous limit function

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example of a convergent sequence of continuous real-valued functions on [0, 1] whose limit function fails to be continuous at an infinite number of points.

I've seen these posts ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439688/finding-a-sequence-of-continuous-real-valued-functions-on-0-1-whose-limit-func), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88769/a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-whose-limit-is-discontinuous-at-infinitely-ma)) but I fail to see how the prevailing example is discontinuous at an infinite number of points and, for the latter, how one would even construct such functions converging to the Thomae function. That being said, I'm looking for clarification or another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maybe more "immediate" example is

$$
f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=0$,} \\
x\cos^{2n}\left(\frac1x\right) & \text{if $0 < x \le 1$.}
\end{cases}
$$

For each $x$ of the form $\frac1{k\pi}, k\in \mathbb Z, k \ge 1$, the $\cos^{2n}$ term will be equal to $1$ for each $n$, so $f_n(x) = x$ for those $x$ and so the limit at such a point will also be $x=\frac1{k\pi}.$

At each other argument $x$ besides $0$, we have $|\cos(\frac1x)| < 1$, so there $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}(\frac1x) = 0$ and since $x$ is bounded, so is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 0$.

So the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is a function that is $0$ except on the infinitely many arguements $x=\frac1{k\pi}$, where the function value is $x$. Hence it is not continuous on infinitely many points.

Comment: Does the boundedness of $x$ matter in the second statement if we already know the limit of the $\cos$ term is $0$?

Comment: @throwaway You are right, maybe a better way to say that would have been "... since $x$ is independent of $n$" Boundedness is what's needed, but it's overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's try an example that converges to Thomae's function $T$.

Let's suppose that we have a finite subset $A = \{(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)\}$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$, where $x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n$. Define $I_A$ as the linear interpolation of $A$, i.e.
$$I_A(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{y_{k+1} - y_k}{x_{k+1} - x_k}(x- x_k) + y_k, & \text{if } x_k \le x \le x_{k+1}, \text{where } 1 \le k \le n-1. \end{cases}$$
There is a small ambiguity in the above definition when $x = x_m$ for some $2 \le m \le n-1$, but regardless of whether you consider $k = m$ or $k = m - 1$ in the above definition, we always have $I_A(x_m) = y_m$, even when $m = 1$ or $m = n$.

In our function, we will consider
$$A_n = \left\{\left(\frac{k}{m}, T\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)\right) : 0 \le k \le m \le n, m \neq 0\right\},$$
i.e. all the rational points on the graph of Thomae's function (on $[0, 1]$) where the least denominator is at most $n$. You could also consider $A_n$ as the points in $\operatorname{Graph} T$ that lie on or above the line $y = \frac{1}{n}$. Naturally, we let $f_n = I_{A_n}$. Here is a plot of the first four such functions:

[image: f_1, \ldots, f_n]

So, we now have some claims to prove. First, I claim that $f_{n+1} \le f_n$ for all $n$. Since $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$, it suffices to show that the new points in $A_{n+1}$ lie below the graph of $f_n$. That is, if $(x, y) \in A_{n+1} \setminus A_n$, then $f_n(x) > y$. Why does this hold? Because if $(x, y) \in A_{n+1} \setminus A_n$, then $x = \frac{k}{n+1}$ for some $k$ coprime to $n+1$, and so $y = T(x) = \frac{1}{n+1}$. This function value is less than the minimum value of $f_n$, which is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Thus, the $f_n$ sequence is decreasing. I further claim that, $T \le f_n$ for all $n$. This follows similarly: all the points $(x, y) \in T$ where $y \ge \frac{1}{n}$ are on the graph of $f_n$ already, and every other point lies below $\frac{1}{n}$, the minimum of $f_n$.

Fix a point $x_0 \in [0, 1]$. If $x_0$ is rational with minimum denominator $m$, then $f_n(x_0) = T(x_0) = \frac{1}{m}$ for $n \ge m$, so $f_n(x_0) \to T(x_0)$, as required. So, we assume without loss of generality that $x_0$ is irrational.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. As $x_0$ is irrational, $T$ is continuous at $x_0$, so for all $\varepsilon$, there exists some $\delta$ such that
$$|x - x_0| < \delta \implies |T(x) - T(x_0)| = T(x) < \varepsilon.$$
Choose $m \in \Bbb{N}$ sufficiently small so that $\frac{1}{m} < \delta$. This implies that, any interval with length $2\delta$ must contain at least two points of the form $\frac{k}{m}$ where $k$ is an integer. The interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ is such an interval, and the centre, $x_0$, must therefore lie between two consecutive such points. That is, we have, for some $k$ (necessarily between $1$ and $m$),
$$x_0 - \delta < \frac{k-1}{m} < x < \frac{k}{m} < x_0 + \delta.$$
Note that $(x_0, f_m(x_0))$ lies on the line segment connecting $\left(\frac{k-1}{m},T\left(\frac{k-1}{m}\right)\right)$ and $\left(\frac{k}{m},T\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)\right)$, which implies that
$$f_m(x_0) \le \max\left\{T\left(\frac{k-1}{m}\right),T\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)\right\}.$$
But, since $\frac{k-1}{m}$ and $\frac{k}{m}$ lie on $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, we therefore have
$$\max\left\{T\left(\frac{k-1}{m}\right),T\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)\right\} < \varepsilon.$$
Hence, for every irrational $x_0$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have some $m$ such that $f_m(x_0) < \varepsilon$. Since $f_n(x_0)$ is a decreasing sequence and $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we see that $f_n(x_0) \to 0 = T(x_0)$ as $n \to \infty$, completing the irrational case.

This completes the proof that $f_n \to T$ pointwise.